# Access variable from different ion-views containing ion-content

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, ionic-view

I just started working with Ionic and have a HTML-snippet as follows:

```
<!-- part of index.html -->
<body data-ng-app="myapp" data-ng-cloak>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive"></ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

Ui-router inside Ionic includes the desired view inside the `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` tags as desired.

Let's have a look at my login view:

```
<!-- partials/login.html -->

<ion-view view-title="Anmelden">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list list-inset" data-ng-form="forms.login">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="email" name="mail" data-ng-model="user.mail" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="password" name="password" data-ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Kennwort" required>
            </label>
            <button data-ng-click="logIn()" class="button button-full button-positive">
                Login
            </button>
            <button ui-sref="loginRegister" class="button button-full button-positive">
                Create Account
            </button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

If login fails, the user is redirected to another view like:

```
<!-- partials/login_failed.html -->

<ion-view view-title="Login failed">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list list-inset" data-ng-form="forms.login">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="email" name="mail" data-ng-model="user.mail" placeholder="E-Mail-Adress" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="password" name="password" data-ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" required>
            </label>
            <button data-ng-click="logIn()" class="button button-full button-positive">
                Retry
            </button>
            <button data-ng-click="resetPassword()" class="button button-full button-positive">
                Reset Password
            </button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The states are and the controller are defined as:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'UserController'
    })
    .state('loginFailed', {
        url: '/login/failed',
        templateUrl: 'partials/login_failed.html',
        controller: 'UserController'
    })
})

.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.forms = {};

    $scope.logIn = function() {
        var user = $scope.user
        if ($scope.forms.login.$valid) {
            console.log('Form valid');
        } else {
            console.log('Form invalid');
        }
    };
    $scope.register = function() {
        var user = $scope.user
        if ($scope.forms.login.$valid) {
            console.log('Form valid');
        } else {
            console.log('Form invalid');
        }
    };
    $scope.resetPassword = function() {
        var mail = $scope.user.mail
        console.log('Reset user password', mail);
        $state.go('loginReset')

    };
}])
```

So if the login fails I want to display the user's mail address in the desired input element to provide a better usability which would be done by using the same model variable.

However, since I have a `ion-content` element inside each view their scopes are isolated from the other ones as stated in the [API docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/).

I tried to gain access by prepending `$parent.` to the `data-ng-model` attribute which should reference to the outer scope of the surrounding `ion-view` tag which should then be accessible by e.g. writing

```
    <!-- just last three lines of view following -->
    </ion-content>
    {{ user.mail }}
</ion-view>
```

at the end of the view. However, this does not seem to be the case.

I am pretty sure that this issue results out of scope inheritance and the hierarchically structure of scope elements inside the DOM. Unfortunately, I do not get the point here. First of all I thought that might be a problem of not using the object notation for two-way-bindings, but I should have fixed that possible problem.

How can I access the data model from all injected views which contain `ion-content` elements with their own scope? Chaining `$parent` elements like `$parent.$parent.` does not seem to be applicable as a general approach and does not lead to the desired results as described above.